# StencilJS Component Styles

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

What is the proper way to use the `styles` option/property of the `ComponentDecorator`? Using the `styles` property with the default `my-name` component from the repository [stencil-component-starter](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter) doesn't seem to affect the styles of the respective component nor generate something like a `<style>` tag in the `<head>`. How is `styles` intended to work? Or has it not been implemented yet? If the goal is to avoid having a separate CSS asset that needs to be loaded, but provide styles for the component, would `styles` be the right choice or is there another property such as `host` would need to be used?

Below is a sample component generated from the stencil-component-starter][1](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter) with `stylesUrl` @Component property replaced with a `styles` property and setting `font-size` property. No errors are generated during `dev` or `build` tasks.

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-name',
  styles: `my-name { font-size: 24px; }`
})
export class MyName {

  @Prop() first: string;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello, my name is {this.first}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`ComponentDecorator` is defined as:

```
export interface ComponentOptions {
    tag: string;
    styleUrl?: string;
    styleUrls?: string[] | ModeStyles;
    styles?: string;
    shadow?: boolean;
    host?: HostMeta;
    assetsDir?: string;
    assetsDirs?: string[];
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with latest **version 0.0.6-22**, and it seems to work completely now.

While compiling, it will tell you if your styles contents is valid or not (mainly looking for valid selectors).

Here is a working example (with a simple string):

```
import { Component, Prop } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: "inline-css-example",
  styles: 'inline-css-example { font-size: 24px; }'
})
export class InlineCSSExampleComponent {
  @Prop() first: string;

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, my name is {this.first}</div>;
  }
}
```

This one works too, with ES6 Template Strings (just showing multiline):

```
import { Component, Prop } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: "inline-templatestring-css-example",
  styles: `
    inline-templatestring-css-example {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  `
})
export class InlineCSSExampleComponent {
  @Prop() first: string;

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, my name is {this.first}</div>;
  }
}
```

(EDITed to show evolution since 0.0.6-13)

Comment: Thank you! This is strange that `styles` only works in conjunction with `styleUrl`. My goal was to avoid having a CSS file generated and referenced by the built assets. Perhaps this will be refined in the future and the `style` contents will be somehow bundled with the built assets' JS.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderStaroselsky What do you mean with "only wirks in conjuction..." ? Do you need both 'cause the sample in this answer only has ```styles```

Comment: @MatthiasMax the original goal was to use something along the lines of injected styles using the `styles` property to avoid needing a separate stylesheet. Since the time of question/answer a number of critical updates have been made to StencilJS including injected styles. This is no longer an issue, thanks!